# Why must I give user & password each time I connect a drive from windows seven to my samba server?

Tags: windows-7, samba

On a windows 7 and after each reboot I must give user & password to connect the samba shares (even if I ask windows to remember them).

I use samba 3.6.3 on ubuntu 12.04 server.
Samba authetication is based on system's users.

Why windows 7 re-ask for user & password again and agian ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check you Credential Manager on you Windows 7 machine to make sure that your credentials for Samba shares are saved. Also, try to map the network drive rather than just access shares directly.

Comment: I've noticed the same thing as in the question. In Windows XP saving credentials worked more or less without problem, but Vista and 7 happen to "forget" the credentials.

Comment: I've logged in using the pattern: MYWORKGROUP\USERNAME and this time it automatically appended a new entry in the Credential Manager.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a network map using the /persistent in order to save the connection properties for future log on's.

Comment: I'am not expert, it a windows 7 option ?